# Python for-loop on a list doesn't get expected results

Tags: python, for-loop, sum

I'm new on Python and trying to make run a blackjack simulator I found in the web. However there are some sentences that are not working as expected. I have tried several ways to do the same task without success.

This is the portion of the code

```
# deal player to 12 or higher
        while sum(player_cards) <= 12:
            exit = False
            player_cards.append(deck.pop(0))
            # check for limit 
            if sum(player_cards) > 21:
                print("--players_cards > 21")
                exit = True
                # check for an ace and convert to 1 if found
                for i, card in enumerate(player_cards):
                    print("--card " + str(card))
                    if card == 11:
                        player_cards[i] = 1
                        exit = False
                    else:
                        return -1   
            if exit:
                break   


        # deal dealer on soft 17
        while sum(dealer_cards) <= 16:
            exit = False
            dealer_cards.append(deck.pop(0))
            # check for limit 
            if sum(dealer_cards) > 21:
                exit = True
                # check for an ace and convert to 1 if found
                for i, card in enumerate(dealer_cards):
                    if card == 11:
                        dealer_cards[i] = 1
                        exit = False
            if exit:
                break
        

        p_sum = sum(player_cards)
        d_sum = sum(dealer_cards)
        
        print("player " + str(player_cards) )
        print("dealer " + str(dealer_cards) )
```

The code above is trying to simulate the cards given to a player and the dealer. Basically the issue arrives when the hand sum is over 21. I have put some print instructions to check the results.

This is some partial output

```
    player [10, 10]
    dealer [5, 6, 10]
    --players_cards > 21
    --card 3
    player [10, 10]
    dealer [10, 9]
    --players_cards > 21
    --card 3
    player [7, 10]
    dealer [5, 10, 5]
```

It makes no sense at all.
I see two issues (is maybe just one).

1. The line "--player_cards > 21" should be printed when sum(player_cards) > 21, but instead is printed when the cards sum are 20 [10. 10] and 17 [7, 10].
2. The for loop should print all the card values for the player hand [10, 10] or [7, 10]. Instead it prints a 3 (??)

I tried to change the for loop using

```
for i in range(len(player_cards)):
                if player_cards[i] == 11:
        player_cards[i] = 1
        exit = False
```

But results are similar.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Player had `[10, 10]`. Then they were dealt a `3` so `--players_cards > 21` was printed.

Comment: Right.  Your problem is the code ordering.  You're diagnosing the bust before you print the cards.  Consider dividing this into a separate functions, so that "dealing", "evaluating" and "printing" are done separately.  That would allow you to avoid the duplication you currently have, by reusing the same code for player and dealer.

Comment: I found it! `if card == 11:
                        player_cards[i] = 1
                        exit = False
                    else:
                        return -1   ` the if was not allowing to do the full for-loop, returning when card != 11